# Share photo to twitter from Android

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, share, twitter-fabric

Hi I am trying to use the TweetComposer within the fabric library to tweet a photo. However, once the intent to Twitter is requested twitter crashes providing no error message whatsoever. I was hoping someone else had has a similar experience with this? Here is the code I am using.

```
   File newFile = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "snapshot.jpg");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,fos);
            fos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

 TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(getActivity()).text("TWEEEET")
       .image(Uri.fromFile(newFile));
        builder.show();
```

It does work when I don't add an image!

Twitter presents a not supported media error when adding the image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I managed to solve it! It turned out I was trying to share a recycled bitmap!